# Question on the TensorFlow object detection api and image/format that is not jpeg(eg dicom or numpy array)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

I like to use the object detection api from tensorflow with dicom images instead of jpg.

In the documentation:
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#create-tensorflow-records
I find the following code

```
    # ...
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    # ...

    image_format = b'jpg'
    # ...

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
```

I have successfully saved a tfrecord with the above format, where encoded_jpg is a bytestring of a numpy array of the dicom file.

1. However I ask myself how to set image_format and whether this is needed and where it is documented ?
2. Furthermore I would like to know if it is in general possible to use the tensorflow objection api with dicom files or if the tensorflow object detection api is restricted to jpg.

@j2abro
I want explicitly not to convert my dicom images to jpeg, because jpeg as far as understood have 8 bit per pixel and my dicom files have 12 bit per pixel. I want to use the lossless version of my data.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, how about converting the DICOM to JPEG? Then you can use the code you have.

```
med2image -i file.dcm -d out
```

The example above is from [med2image](https://pypi.org/project/med2image/) Python library.